# Crear filas de una lista con los elementos de una columna en pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Quiero crear filas con los elementos de las columnas que están dentro de un array, partiendo de:

```
>>> dataset = sorted_dataset.traspose()
>>> dateset.head()

                      0                1                 2  ...         7434
        [ -0.0016479492,   [0.0021362305,    [0.0001220731,     [0.008117676,
Signal   -0.00036621094,      0.00390625,     0.0005493164,      0.008911133,
           0.0005187988,    0.0036621094,    9.1552734e-05,      0.008972168,
                    ...              ...              ...                ...
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que busco es que el primer elemento de cada array conformen la primera fila, el segundo la segunda... etc. Todos los arrays tienen el mismo número de elementos.

Comment: Hola a todos si alguien sabe como pasar estas columnas de array a filas por elemento del array agradecería toda ayuda, llevo unas horas provando diferentes cosas pero no soy capaz, gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola Xavier, bienvenido. Dos observaciones, no debes usar imágenes para mostrar el código, copia y pagalo siempre como texto. Las imágenes hace difícil reproducir el problema, complican la legibilidad en dispositivos móviles, etc. Puedes usarlas, pero de forma accesoria.

Comment: Segundo, la salida esperada seria que cada array conforme una fila o que el primer elemento de cada array conformen la primera fila, el segundo la segunda... Es decir, la salida esperada para la primera fila seria `-0.0016479492 ,-0.00036621094,..`. o `-0.0016479492, 0.0021362305, ...`. Creo que buscas la segunda, pero por aclararlo. Por otro lado, ¿que indice debería tener el dataframe? ¿Todos los arrays tienen la misma longitud?

Comment: Gracias por las indicaciones FJSevilla. Si como dices seria: que el primer elemento de cada array conformen la primera fila, el segundo la segunda... etc..

Comment: ¿Tienen todos los arrays el mismo numero de elementos? Esto es muy importante, porque hace la operación trivial o algo mas complicada...

Comment: Si todos los arrays tienen el mismo número de elementos, hay 7440 arrays (columnas) con 44311 elementos cada uno.

Comment: Disculpad mi ignorancia novata al exponer el problema, espero ir mejorando, gracias por el interés y la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a crear un ejemplo muy simplificado pero que represente tu problema primer:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
         0: [np.array([1, 4, 7])],
         1: [np.array([2, 5, 8])],
         2: [np.array([3, 6, 9])]
    }, index=("Signal",))
```

Con esto tenemos un DataFrame como el siguiente:

```
>>> df
                    0          1          2
    Signal  [1, 4, 7]  [2, 5, 8]  [3, 6, 9]
```

**Si todos los arrays tienen el mismo numero de elementos**, para convertirlos en filas (de forma que el primer elemento de cada array conformen la primera fila, el segundo la segunda, etc) podemos hacer uso de [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) pasandole todas las columnas del DataFrame:

```
>>> df.explode(column=list(df.columns))

        0  1  2
Signal  1  2  3
Signal  4  5  6
Signal  7  8  9
```

Comment: Sorpresa, parece ser que los arrays no son del mismo tamaño, este es el error que me da: 

ValueError: columns must have matching element counts                                                  Alguna idea? gracias!

Comment: He provado esto:dataset.set_index(dataset.columns).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()                        pero meda el error:                                                                                                              ValueError:Length mismatch: Expected 1 rows, received array of length 7440                  Entonces lo he pasado por un bucle para cada columna así:                                               for col in dataset.columns:
dataset.set_index([dataset[col]]).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()                             Pero me peta la memoria en colab

Comment: @Xavier eso complica las cosas, lo primero que tienes que plantearte es que hacer con los datos que faltan o sobran, dado que todas las filas tiene que tener el mismo numero de elementos (columnas). Puedes crear las filas y dejar los items de los arrays mas cortos como 0, NaN o lo que te convenga. Tambien puedes "recortar" los arrays mas largos, con lo que tu DataFrame tendria tantas filas como el array con menos elementos. Tanto si descartas datos como si rellenas con ceros,  Nan, etc, tambien debes plantearte si hacerlo a final de los arrays, al principio, etc.

Comment: De acuerdo me lo voy a mirar bien, muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Ummm, ¿la estructura de tu dataframe actualmente  es como la de mi ejemplo (aparte de que uso enteros como datos, eso es irrelevante)? ¿que te muestra si ejecutas `np.info(dataset[0].iloc[0])` **antes de aplicar explode**?

Comment: Perdón he eliminado el mensaje anterior por que creo que ha sido un error mio, al reducir la longitud se han generado dos corchetes y creo que eso es lo que ha hecho que después explode no haya trabajado correctamente. Voy a corregirlo y espero no tener problemas. Muchas gracias por la ayuda FJSevilla, te lo agradezco mucho. Si tengo problemas atacaré de nuevo, sorry!

Comment: Hola FJSevilla, ya he solucionado el problema de los arrays, efectivamente tu solución con explode ha funcionado perfectamente, gracias por todo. Saludos.